# How to access the iOS system font programmatically

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch

I am trying to change the font size of the title of a navigation bar. I know I can set its attributes using:

```
var attributes = [ NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.blackColor(), NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: "the font name", size: 18)! ]
```

...

```
 self.navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = attributes
```

What I cannot seem to find is the correct 'System' font name.

I was after the default, a.k.a System, font name. I tried printing all the available fonts only to discover it does not belong to a family and does not seem to have an explicit name.

Answer (score 112, accepted):

I think you need:

```
NSFontAttributeName : UIFont.systemFontOfSize(19.0)
```

Or the bold version:

```
NSFontAttributeName : UIFont.boldSystemFontOfSize(19.0)
```

See [this guide](http://ivomynttinen.com/blog/the-ios-7-design-cheat-sheet/) for more info on user interface guidelines and fonts.

Comment: Shouldn't be `.boldSystemFontOfSize(17.0)`  for the navigation bar title?

Comment: Yeah, could be, depends on what you want. I've updated my answer. Thanks!

Comment: It would be cool if you add this to your answer: http://ivomynttinen.com/blog/the-ios-7-design-cheat-sheet/  Font sizes are multiplied for @2x resolution so the OP should use the font size / 2 from that article.

Comment: Sure, although I think it exceeds the OP's needs. Thanks again.

Comment: You're welcome! Yes, it exceeds the need of the OP but I believe this would be a good reference for others who will read this post.

Answer (score 30):

You can access the system font like this, and even set the weight of the font:

- [Swift 3](https://swift.org/blog/swift-3-1-released/), [Swift 4](https://swift.org/blog/swift-4-1-released/)

  `UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 18, weight: UIFontWeightLight)`
- [Swift 2](https://swift.org/blog/swift-2-2-released/)

  `UIFont.systemFontOfSize(18, weight: UIFontWeightLight)`

For the font weight you have the choice between those constants, there available from [iOS 8.2](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/releasenotes/General/iOS82APIDiffs/modules/UIKit.html):

```
UIFontWeightUltraLight,
UIFontWeightThin,
UIFontWeightLight,
UIFontWeightRegular,
UIFontWeightMedium,
UIFontWeightSemibold,
UIFontWeightBold,
UIFontWeightHeavy,
UIFontWeightBlack
```

Comment: This is Swift3 ... nice!

Comment: Thanks @ChrisAllinson !

Answer (score 18):

SWIFT 4+:
shorter version

```
UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 14.0, weight: .regular)
```

Answer (score 6):

(In line with the answer from Philippe for the latest version)

- Swift 4

  `UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 18, weight: UIFont.Weight.light)`

Answer (score 4):

Besides all the answers, it's a better idea to use system font with system styles instead of defining custom sizes and weights. To access them programmatically, for example for the headline, you can use this method:

```
let font = UIFont.preferredFont(forTextStyle: .headline)
```

I know it is a valid code at least for Swift 5.

Comment: Refer this to Add font size 
UIFont.preferredFont(forTextStyle: .body).withSize(14)

Answer (score 2):

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSFontAttributeName : UIFont.systemFontOfSize(6)]
```

Answer (score 2):

Just use methods of UIFont (swift):

```
let sysFont: UIFont = UIFont.systemFontOfSize(UIFont.systemFontSize())
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

**Try the below code:**

```
self.navigationController!.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name:"Arial", size:14.0)!, NSForegroundColorAttributeName:UIColor.blackColor()]
```